# Matplotlib slider widgets (user-defined script-generated) aren't triggering recalculation and plot update

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, widget

Here is a highly abstracted main program and module. Matplotlib slider widgets should cause the `Data` instances to recalculate and the plot should then update.

Each time a slider is updated, it should pass its new value to the appropriate method defined during the slider's instantiation. For example, moving the first slider should send it's value to `d1.set_a()` which triggers a recalculation of that data, and should then trigger `P.offsets()` (see MODULE) to update the plot.

**Question:** How can I get these user-defined, script-generated Sliders to trigger the data objects and the plot to update? Do the Slider Widgets instances offer more convenient methods than the way I'm doing it here?

MAIN Program:

```
import numpy as np
from MODULE import Data, Plot

x0 = np.linspace(0, 10., 11)
y1, y2 = [0.5 * (1.0 + f(x0)) for f in (np.cos, np.sin)]

d1, d2 = Data('hey', x0, y1), Data('wow', x0, y2) # data generating objects

p = Plot('hey')    # plot object

p.add_slider(d1, 'set_a', d1.a, (0.2, 1.0))
p.add_slider(d1, 'set_p', d1.p, (0.5, 2.0))
p.add_slider(d2, 'set_a', d2.a, (0.2, 1.0))
p.add_slider(d2, 'set_p', d2.p, (0.5, 2.0))

p.plotme((d1, d2))
```

Current result, sliders move but don't trigger recalculation/replotting:

[image: slider test]

MODULE:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider

class Plot(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.sliders = []
        self.axcolor = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'
        self.fig = plt.figure()

    def sliderfunc(self, value):
        print('sliderfunc')       # currently not getting here
        for (obj, P) in self.OPs:
            P.set_offsets(obj.xy.T)
        self.fig.canvas.draw_idle()

    def add_slider(self, obj, method, nominal, limits):
        ybot = 0.03 * (len(self.sliders) + 1)
        name = obj.name + '.' + method 
        ax_slider   = plt.axes([0.25, ybot, 0.50, 0.02], facecolor=self.axcolor)
        slider      = Slider(ax_slider, name, limits[0], limits[1],
                             valinit=nominal)
        slider.on_changed(getattr(obj, method)) # this may not be right
        self.sliders.append(slider)
        return slider

    def plotme(self, objs):
        ybot = 0.03 * (len(self.sliders) + 3)
        A = plt.axes([0.15, ybot, 0.65, 0.50])
        self.OPs = []
        for obj in objs:
            P = A.scatter(obj.x, obj.y)
            self.OPs.append((obj, P))
        plt.show()

class Data(object):
    def __init__(self, name, x0, y0):
        self.name = name
        self.a = 1.0
        self.p = 1.0
        self.x0, self.y0 = x0, y0
        self.setstuff(a=1.0, p=1.0)
    def setstuff(self, a=None, p=None):
        if a != None:
            self.set_a(a)
        if p != None:
            self.set_p(p)
    def set_a(self, a):
        self.a = a
        self.x = self.a * self.x0
        self.y = self.y0**self.p
        self.xy = np.vstack((self.x, self.y))
    def set_p(self, p):
        self.p = p
        self.x = self.a * self.x0
        self.y = self.y0**self.p
        self.xy = np.vstack((self.x, self.y))
```

Comment: Possibly you just forgot to assign the `Slider` to a variable. If you don't to that it will be garbage collected (as all objects without reference will in python) and removed from memory instantly after its creation.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest nope that's not it. The contents of the `p.sliders` list still contains four `matplotlib.widgets.Slider` instances and I can still read their data.

Comment: Ok, so you will need to provide a runnable code, such that one can actually test this. (Currently there is some undefined variable, so I cannot run it)

Comment: There is a main program and a module, you have to put both in the same place and they run fine together. Do you want me to put them together as a single script?

Comment: I have again copied back from the screen to two new files here as a test (PROGRAM.py and MODULE.py) and they still run just fine together (without error) for me. Can you tell me what variable it is that is not working for you?

Comment: I've closed and re-opened iTerm2 (MacOS) and renamed to MODULEy.py to avoid any conflicts with the generic word MODULE (updated import line in main program as well), and it still runs without error for me. I'm using a fairly new (few months old) Anaconda Python-3 installation.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest can you please show the error message that you are getting? Thanks!

Comment: I show O and fig undefined in sliderfunc. Strangely I get no traceback even when I adjust the sliders. Same result in ipython and terminal.

Comment: @bitchaser yes that's wrong, Thanks! I've hopefully fixed both in the question, in the definition of `sliderfunc(self, value)`. I should have caught that when I abstracted. It didn't show any error for me though, can I ask how you were able to see that? https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGufs.png

Comment: Spyder flags them as in error. Apparently sliderfunc is never called. It looked like both sliderfunc and add_slider have code which tries to update the plot. I'm out of my area of expertise here, but couldn't resist trying your code. I use Anaconda python also.

Comment: @bitchaser okay maybe it's time for me to use a "grown-up" editor. My not knowing how to properly call sliderfunc is central to the question. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest update: I've started using Spyder now, fixed the undefined variable (the code always ran but that would have been a problem soon) and some other small cleanups, show warning/error list is now empty. Added print statement in `sliderfunc()` to confirm that it never gets called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The individual sliders need to perform different actions, so each slider needs its own callback. Inside of it you may of course then call the same function (`sliderfunc`) to update the plot.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider


class Plot(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.sliders = []
        self.fig = plt.figure()

    def sliderfunc(self):
        for (obj, P) in self.OPs:
            P.set_offsets(obj.xy.T)
        self.fig.canvas.draw_idle()

    def add_slider(self, obj, method, nominal, limits):
        ybot = 0.03 * (len(self.sliders) + 1)
        name = obj.name + '.' + method 
        ax_slider   = plt.axes([0.25, ybot, 0.50, 0.02], facecolor="w")
        slider      = Slider(ax_slider, name, limits[0], limits[1],
                             valinit=nominal)

        def callback(val):
            getattr(obj, method)(val)
            self.sliderfunc()

        slider.on_changed(callback)
        self.sliders.append(slider)
        return slider

    def plotme(self, objs):
        ybot = 0.03 * (len(self.sliders) + 3)
        A = plt.axes([0.15, ybot, 0.65, 0.50])
        self.OPs = []
        for obj in objs:
            P = A.scatter(obj.x, obj.y)
            self.OPs.append((obj, P))
        plt.show()

class Data(object):
    def __init__(self, name, x0, y0):
        self.name = name
        self.a = 1.0
        self.p = 1.0
        self.x0, self.y0 = x0, y0
        self.update()

    def update(self):
        self.x = self.a * self.x0
        self.y = self.y0**self.p
        self.xy = np.vstack((self.x, self.y))

    def set_a(self, val):
        self.a = val
        self.update()

    def set_p(self, val):
        self.p = val
        self.update()


x0 = np.linspace(0, 10., 11)
y1, y2 = [0.5 * (1.0 + f(x0)) for f in (np.cos, np.sin)]

d1, d2 = Data('hey', x0, y1), Data('wow', x0, y2) # data generating objects

p = Plot('hey')    # plot object

p.add_slider(d1, 'set_a', d1.a, (0.2, 1.0))
p.add_slider(d1, 'set_p', d1.p, (0.5, 2.0))
p.add_slider(d2, 'set_a', d2.a, (0.2, 1.0))
p.add_slider(d2, 'set_p', d2.p, (0.5, 2.0))

p.plotme((d1, d2))
```

Comment: Oh, this is really, really beautiful, wow! I think it would have taken quite a while for me to figure this out, but now that I see it it's clear as day. Thank you very much!